# Why does my new swift file have missing codes?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

When I generate a new swift file, there is only: import Foundation on display. There are no class or function codes that would usually be auto-generated when I create a new file. I tried to fill them in manually and run the codes but I keep getting error of: Thread 1:signal SIGABRT. How do I fix this?

Comment: have you created swift file or viewcontroller file ?

Comment: swift file. i just right clicked, add a new file, then chose swift file

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image] insted of creating swiftfile   please try to create `swift viewcontrollerfile`. pleasee check the image.

to create swift viewcontroller file
file->new->file->Coco Touch Class->ViewControllerfile

Comment: ah the coco touch class! now it works. thank you so much

Comment: @amateur You can use the new swift file also. Just `import UIKit`